# A way for a batch using %1 to goto a specific part depending on the file format

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

How could I get the file format from the file so that depending on the Files Format it goes to the correct code using the sample code below

Or is there another way to get similar results

```
if "%Format%"==".flac" GOTO DAudioFLAC
if "%Format%"==".ogg" GOTO DAudioOGG
if "%Format%"==".mp4" GOTO Settings
if "%Format%"==".gif" GOTO Gif
```

Comment: `if /i "%~x1" == ".flac ..` or (with adapting your labels)  just `goto :%~x1`. An extension not covered by a label will end the script with a "label not found" message.

Answer (score 1):

```
set "format=%~x1"
if /i ...
```

the `/i` makes the comparison case-insensitive.

`%~?n`, where `n` is a `metavariable` (0..9 for procedure arguments, the loop-variable name in a `for`-loop) and `?` is a combination of `fdnxtsz` can be used to select the `F`ull name, `D`rive, `N`ame, e`X`tension, date & `T`ime, `S`hort-(name) or si`Z`e of the file whose name is in the `metavariable`